# Pandas separate column containing string with a semicolon to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am unable to split a pandas series that contains a semicolon. Is it because I am using the column name ('Social_Media') as an index or is it because python wont recognise a semicolon as a split character? Or is something wrong with my script?

```
#Filters the NaN columns
df2 = df[df['Social_Media'].notnull()]
# Splitter for semicolon
df2['Social_Media'].apply(lambda x: x.split(';')[0])

#This is my output after the split
Timestamp                             
2017-06-01 18:10:46          Twitter;Facebook;Instagram;WhatsApp;Google+
2017-06-01 19:24:04          Twitter;Facebook;Instagram;WhatsApp;Google+
2017-06-01 19:25:21          Twitter;Facebook;Instagram;WhatsApp;Google+
```

What I need to see as output.

```
Timestamp                    name_a  name_b   name_c    name_d   name_e
2017-06-01 18:10:46          Twitter Facebook Instagram WhatsApp Google+
2017-06-01 19:24:04          Twitter Facebook Instagram WhatsApp Google+
2017-06-01 19:25:21          Twitter Facebook Instagram WhatsApp Google+
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked great. Thanks also for the addition recommendation on how to handle a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

```
df = df['Social_Media'].str.split(';', expand=True).add_prefix('name_')
print (df)
                      name_0    name_1     name_2    name_3   name_4
Timestamp                                                           
2017-06-01 18:10:46  Twitter  Facebook  Instagram  WhatsApp  Google+
2017-06-01 19:24:04  Twitter  Facebook  Instagram  WhatsApp  Google+
2017-06-01 19:25:21  Twitter  Facebook  Instagram  WhatsApp  Google+
```

And for columns names by alphabet:

```
import string
L = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
names = dict(zip(range(len(L)), ['name_' + x for x in  L]))

df = df['Social_Media'].str.split(';', expand=True).rename(columns=names)
print (df)
                      name_a    name_b     name_c    name_d   name_e
Timestamp                                                           
2017-06-01 18:10:46  Twitter  Facebook  Instagram  WhatsApp  Google+
2017-06-01 19:24:04  Twitter  Facebook  Instagram  WhatsApp  Google+
2017-06-01 19:25:21  Twitter  Facebook  Instagram  WhatsApp  Google+
```